# Iterating over an object that contains arrays

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array

I have an object that has an array inside with another object inside.  I iterate over the object and array to print out the first name and last name of the people inside the array of objects.  I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.
Without having to use obj[i].first_name + " " + obj[i].last_name

Here is my code

```
    var users = {
 'Students': [ 
     {first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'},
     {first_name : 'John', last_name : 'Rosales'},
     {first_name : 'Mark', last_name : 'Guillen'},
     {first_name : 'KB', last_name : 'Tonel'}
  ],
 'Instructors': [
     {first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Choi'},
     {first_name : 'Martin', last_name : 'Puryear'}
  ]
 }
    for(item in users)
    {
        console.log(item);
        var obj = users[item]
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            var obj2 = obj[i];
      var name = "";
            for(j in obj2)
            {
          name += obj2[j] + " ";
            }
      console.log(name);
      name ="";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with `obj[i].first_name + " " + obj[i].last_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, yes, there is a better way: [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and using [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

In the following snippet, it uses `Object.keys` and `array.reduce` to concatenate all arrays in the object into one array, `array.map` to generate an array of name strings from that array, and `array.forEach` to ultimately loop through the names array and print names.

```js
const users = {
  'Students': [ 
    {first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'},
    {first_name : 'John', last_name : 'Rosales'},
    {first_name : 'Mark', last_name : 'Guillen'},
    {first_name : 'KB', last_name : 'Tonel'}
  ],
  'Instructors': [
    {first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Choi'},
    {first_name : 'Martin', last_name : 'Puryear'}
  ]
}

Object.keys(users)
  .reduce((names, userType) => names.concat(users[userType]), [])
  .map(userObject => `${userObject.first_name} ${userObject.last_name}`)
  .forEach(name => console.log(name));
```

If you're not into ES6, here's the ES5 equivalent:

```js
const users = {
  'Students': [ 
    {first_name:  'Michael', last_name : 'Jordan'},
    {first_name : 'John', last_name : 'Rosales'},
    {first_name : 'Mark', last_name : 'Guillen'},
    {first_name : 'KB', last_name : 'Tonel'}
  ],
  'Instructors': [
    {first_name : 'Michael', last_name : 'Choi'},
    {first_name : 'Martin', last_name : 'Puryear'}
  ]
}

Object.keys(users)
  .reduce(function(names, userType) {
    return names.concat(users[userType]);
  }, [])
  .map(function(userObject) {
    return ((userObject.first_name) + " " + (userObject.last_name));
  })
  .forEach(function(name) {
    return console.log(name);
  });
```

As for your code:

- Indentation needs to be more consistent.
- Names in JS follow the camelCase convention.
- Most of JS code I've seen use the "egyptian braces" (collapsed braces).
- Note that variables declared with `var` is function-scoped. Loops don't scope `var`s locally.
- `for-in` loops should be guarded with an `object.hasOwnProperty` check.